# Как добавить полосу прокрутки в groupbox чтобы один из элементов был статичен?

Tags: c#

Если такое возможно. Просто у меня в groupbox есть текстовое поле, а под ним надписи, которые создаются динамически на основе данных из sql. Чтобы зафиксировать текстовое поле можно извратиться и под ним сделать ещё один groupbox, в который и добавлять надписи, но тк код у меня и так плохой, в силу неопытности, то может можно это как-то оптимизировать?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
      List<Label> A = new List<Label>();
      //Прочий код
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       groupBox1.Show();
       SqlCommand _sqCom1 = new SqlCommand();
       _sqCom1.Connection = _sqCon;
       _sqCom1.CommandText = "select mess, sender from message";
       SqlDataAdapter _dP1 = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqCom1);
       DataSet _dSet1 = new DataSet();
       _dP1.Fill(_dSet1);
       int max = _dSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
       for(int i=0; i< max; i++)
       {
         if(((string)_dSet1.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] == sender)||(max>10))
         {
           //Поможет ли здесь объявление свойства AutoScroll = true?
           Label b = new Label();
           A.Add(b);
           b.AutoSize = true;
           b.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 20 + 28 * (A.Count - 1));
           b.Name = "label" + A.Count;
           b.TabIndex = A.Count + 1;
           b.Text = "" + _dSet1.Tables[0].Rows[i][0];
           Controls.Add(b);
         }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: В `GroupBox` поместите `Panel`. А уже в эту панель добавляйте динамически данные. И у этой панели поставьте автоскролл.

Comment: А лучше возьмите, например, `DataGridView`. И не нужно мучиться с ручным добавлением контролов.

Comment: Вот это сравнение `== sender` очень странно. Здесь `sender` - это кнопка (Button), по нажатию на которую был вызван этот обработчик события. Эта кнопка никак не может быть в датасете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ```sender``` в данном случае это строка с именем, просто я забыл её вначале описать. Опечатался :) А на счёт Panel, то думаю - да, это должно сработать